# all.equal with a list and quote(expr = )

Tags: r

Some time ago I made a function that checks whether an argument is missing and if it is, it returns an informative error. It looks like this:

```
#' Check if arguments are missing and raise error if they are
#'
#' Checks if arguments are missing and raises an error if they are. Put this in the beginning of your functions to check the input and give useful errors without writing checking code over and over again.
#' @param var_names (chr vector) Names of variables to check.
#' @param error_msg (chr scalar) A template of the error message to show.
#' @export
#' @examples
#' test_func = function(y) {
#' check_missing("y")
#' T
#' }
#' test_func(y = ) #throws error
#' test_func(y = 1) #returns true
check_missing = function(var_names, error_msg = "[VAR] was missing! Please supply the input and try again.") {

  #parent.frame as list
  pf = as.list(parent.frame())

  #check each if missing
  for (name in var_names) {
    #is it there at all?
    if (!name %in% names(pf)) {
      stop(name + " is not even found in the parent.frame! Check the variable names.", call. = F)
    }

    #check if missing
    if (are_equal(pf[[name]], quote(expr = ))) {
      stop(str_replace(error_msg, pattern = "\\[VAR\\]", name), call. = F)
    }
  }

  #all fine
  return(invisible(NULL))
}
```

Function from [this package](https://github.com/Deleetdk/kirkegaard), use with:

```
library(devtools);install_github("deleetdk/kirkegaard");library("kirkegaard")
```

In a particular use case, I get a list as an argument passed to the checker function above. However, this results in:

```
Error in all.equal.list(target, current, ...) : 
  argument "current" is missing, with no default
```

One can reproduce this with this minimal example:

```
> all.equal(list(), quote(expr = ))
Error in all.equal.list(list(), quote(expr = )) : 
  argument "current" is missing, with no default
```

Is there a bug in the base-r function or am I misunderstanding something?

I hacked around the problem by inserting:

```
if (is.list(pf[[name]])) return(invisible(NULL)) #evade bug?
```

before the offending line (the call to `are_equal`, my wrapper for `all.equal`).

Comment: maybe its because `str(quote(expr = ))` returns a `symbol` and not a `list` and hence all.equal.list throws an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should disappear if you use `identical` instead of
`all.equal`.

First of all, note that `quote(expr = )` creates a missing object:

```
test_env <- new.env()
test_env$a <- quote(expr = )

ls.str(test_env)
a : <missing>
```

Next up, note that `all.equal` works fine when both of its arguments
are missing, but fails when only one of them is missing.

```
all.equal(target = quote(expr = ), current = test_env$a)
[1] TRUE

all.equal(target = list(), current = test_env$a)
Error in all.equal.list(target = list(), current = test_env$a) : 
  argument "current" is missing, with no default
```

The reason for this is that `all.equal` first checks if the arguments
are identical - and if not, it tries to do some further kind of
comparison (see `?all.equal` for the details).

This problem is not present if you use `identical` instead of
`all.equal`:

```
identical(x = quote(expr = ), y = test_env$a)
[1] TRUE

identical(x = list(), y = test_env$a)
[1] FALSE
```

Based on this, I guess your code should work if you replace
`(are_equal(pf[[name]], quote(expr = )))` with
`(identical(pf[[name]], quote(expr = )))`.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the function to me. It should be able to tell me whether the objects are equal or not, not throw an error in some rare cases and not in others.

Comment: I agree that this looks like a bug, but the thing is that `all.equal` aims at doing more than `identical`, i.e. it also tries to give us an idea about the amount the two objects differ when they are not equal.  Thus, when `all.equal` have found out that the objects are different, it sends the two arguments into some sub-function that will check if they are *almost equal* (e.g. if they are numerical values that differ by a tiny amount).  I suppose the error is triggered by a sub-function, which then tells us that the main-function should have had a non-missing value for that argument.